# How to make item draggable after ajax call filtering

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

So I got a list of names which are dragable. I have a list of checkboxes with help them I can filter that names. After checking checkbox I make an ajax call. Here is how my list is look like(it is an accordion):

```
        <div id="myAccordion">
        <?php
                echo "<h3>Names</h3>";  
                echo '<ul class="source">';
                echo '<div id="getData"></div>';    
                echo '<div id="hideData">'; 
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY `username` ASC ";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);       
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
                {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                    {  
                        $name = $row["username"];
                        $user_type = $row["user_type"];
                        echo"<li class='item'><span class='closer'>x</span>".$name."</li>";                     
                    }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        echo "0 results";
                    }   
                echo '</div>';                      
                echo '</ul>';
        ?>  
        </div>
```

So after calling ajax i call filter.php and print that:

```
<?php
require_once('inc/database_connection.php');
include 'model/model.project.php';
if($_POST['user_type'])
{
    //unserialize to jquery serialize variable value
    $type=array();

    parse_str($_POST['user_type'],$type); //changing string into array 

    //split 1st array elements
    foreach($type as $ids)
    {
        $ids;
    }
    $types=implode("','",$ids); //change into comma separated value to sub array
    echo "<br>";
    $result = getUserTypeChecked($types);
?>
    <div id="getData">
    <?php 
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {                   
        //echo $rows['username']."<br>";  
        $name = $rows["username"];
        echo '<ul id="source">';
        echo"<li class='item'><span class='closer'>x</span>".$name."<div class='green'></div></li>";    
        echo '</ul>';

    }       
    ?>  
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

So the problem is name stops being draggable after ajax call. How can I achieve this?

### EDIT

Ok, so here is my js for accordion:

```
<script>
    $("#myAccordion").accordion({heightStyle:"content", collapsible:true});
    $("#myAccordion li ").draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone",
         refreshPositions: true,
         start: function (event, ui) {
            sourceElement = $(this);
        },          
    });
</script>
```

And ajax call:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('#getData').hide();
    $('.ids').on('change',function(){ //on checkboxes check
        //sending checkbox value into serialize form
        var hi=$('.ids:checked').serialize();
        if(hi){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: "filter.php",
                data:{user_type:hi},
                success: function(response){
                    //$('#getData').show();
                    document.getElementById('getData').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById("getData").innerHTML = response;
                    $('#hideData').hide();
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('getData').style.display = "none";
            $('#hideData').show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: your javascript will help and a parsed html will be nice

Comment: @madalinivascu didnt get your comment. can you please explain more? thank you

Comment: place the your javascript and the parsed html so we can help you

Comment: @madalinivascu see edit. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reinitialize you plugins after appending the new html in the success function:

```
document.getElementById("getData").innerHTML = response;
$('#hideData').hide();
 $("#myAccordion").accordion({heightStyle:"content", collapsible:true});
    $("#myAccordion li ").draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone",
         refreshPositions: true,
         start: function (event, ui) {
            sourceElement = $(this);
        },          
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

JS works with loaded DOM on page. This means when ever you call sort function, HTML elements must be present on the page.

Let's try to understand what's going on here?

- All html elements loaded first.
- JS trigger and all dragging functionality to loaded DOM.
- Ajax call to fetch new data and replace old DOMs.
- Now drag functionality stops working.
- why? because JS drag function run on old DOM and currently it has been removed.
- need to call the drag function again on new loaded DOM.

**NOTE:** make sure elements or HTML must be loaded before calling JS drag function.